# How do I evaluate the cumulative distribution function P(XY <= a) for a given a and it's pdf's

Tags: probability, statistics

Struggling to understand the following example assignment:

> Let X and Y be independent and unif[0, 1], and let A be the area of a
> rectangle with sides X and Y. Find the pdf of A.

I try to obtain the CDF in order to get to the pdf.
Using the definition of a cdf $$ P( (X, Y) \in B) = \iint_{B}^{} f(x, y) dxdy$$

I get

$$ F_A(a) = P(XY \leq a) = \iint_{B}^{} f(x, y) dxdy $$
where $$ f(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y) = 1$$ since X, Y are independent

The set to be integrated over is: $$ B = {(x, y): 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1, xy \leq a}$$

Now the book comes up with the expression that $$ \iint_{B}^{} f(x, y) dxdy = a + \iint_{0}^{a/x} dydx$$ and limits on x is x0 = a, x1 = 1

This is the part I don't understand how they got. They say one would realize that this would be the case if one draws up the set B.

Comment: in the title you need to derivate the CDF but in the posted exercise they request the pdf...please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that $B=\{\langle x,y\rangle:0\leqslant x\leqslant 1, 0\leqslant y\leqslant 1, xy\leqslant a\}$

That can also be written $B=\{\langle x,y\rangle:0\leqslant x\leqslant 1, 0\leqslant y\leqslant\min\{ 1, a/x\}\}$

Which may be partitioned by $x<a$ and $a\leqslant x$.

---

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(XY\leqslant a) &=\iint_{B} \mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&= \int_0^1\int_0^{\min\{1, a/x\}}\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=\int_0^a\int_0^1\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x+\int_a^1\int_0^{a/x}\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=a+\int_a^1\int_0^{a/x}\mathrm d y~\mathrm d x\\[2ex]&=a-a\ln a\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, Graham! It's clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do a drawing of your problem you will realize that the CDF of A is the area described by the inequality

$$y\leq \frac{a}{x}$$

... in the unit square. That is

$$F_A(a)=a+\int_a^1 \frac{a}{x}dx$$

Derivating the result you get

$$f_A(a)=-\log a\cdot \mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(a)$$

Which is a valid pdf being, $\forall a$

$$f_A(a)\geq 0$$

And

$$\int_0^1 f(a)da=1$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply Tommik! Much appreciated :)